# objective-c if-else statement

Tags: xcode4, if-statement, ios5, uilabel, uitextview

I have both a `UITextLabel` and a `UITextView` occupying the same real estate, point-for-point in my view. I have an `NSMutableArray` allocated to populate the `UITextLabel` based on what the user taps in a table. I would also like to program the app to use the `UITextView` *if and only if* the user taps on **one specific row**. I think this can be accomplished with an if-else (if) statement, but I'm not sure. If that will work, I don't know what to put in the if part. So far, I have this:

```
if (qux == ??) {

    fooTextView.text = textString;

} else {

    fooTextLabel.text = textString;

}
```

---

I don't know what to set the if statement to. I tried to set it to

> if (qux == *the really long code containing the single array statement
>   I want displayed as a UITextView*)

but that returned an error. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get Xcode to recognize my single `NSMutableArray` table cell with the `UITextView` and not (also) with the `UILabel`? As of right now, the app builds but displays the text both in the `UITextView`, so it scrolls and does exactly what I want but also displays in the `UILabel` and is static and visible "underneath" the scrolling `UITextView`.

Also, I'm using an NSMutable Array with initWithObjectAndKeys. In this special case that is the only one of its kind in my `UITableView`, I use a special key that is only used by this particular part of the array. Is it possible to set it up so it's something regarding:

```
if (qux == *NSMutableArray with the special key*) {

    fooTextView.text = textString;

} else {

    fooTextLabel.text = textString;

}
```

And should I be using an if-else if statement or just an if-else statement?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your question. You're mixing a lot of things together. Sum your question up and be more specific.

Comment: I can push the data from my array into either a UITextView or a UILabel outlet. I have a UITableView with 11 rows. Rows 1-10 need to go to the UILabel, and row 11 needs to go to the UITextView. When I link row 11 to the UITextView, the data from this row is pushed to both the UILabel and UITextView. How do I get the date from row 11 to go ONLY to the UITextView and not also the UILabel? I think it's possible with an if-else statement, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0):

Use the UITableView Delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath: you can get you row index from the NSIndexPath (indexPath.row).  The you can use an if-then or a switch to determine which of your controls gets the data.  Make sure you set your UITableView's delegate property to your file owner so the UITableView will call back to you controller.

HTH